# Perl's XML::Compile::WSDL11 -> importDefinitions() does not conserve namespace

Tags: perl, soap, xsd, namespaces, wsdl

I'm implementing a SOAP client in Perl. The server it will send requests to has made available its WSDL and XSD schemas, and I've downloaded them locally to my computer. Now, the API is vast(!), and there is more than 150 schemas (two `.wsdl` and the rest `.xsd`) files.

If I use the opensource `SoapUI`, I may import only the `wsdl`s and everything works perfectly out of the box; requests are sent and appropriate responses are returned: cool!

Now, I'm trying to implement a client in Perl,

```perl
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new;
$wsdl->addWSDL("schema/wsdl/MySuperService.wsdl");
$wsdl->importDefinitions("schema/xsd/MySuperService.xsd");
$wsdl->compileCalls(address => "https://my-web-host:4242/my-super-service");
```

All other `.xsd` are nested by `import` as

```xml
<xs:import namespace="SomeNameSpace" schemaLocation="relative/path/to/an.xsd"/>
```

or with `include` statements like

```xml
<xs:include schemaLocation="rel/path/to/another.xsd/>
```

I understand the documentation of XSD schemas such that `import` brings in definitions by their own namespace, while `include` brings the included definitions into the includer's namespace.

Now, here's the problem: the `importDefinitions()` from `XML::Compile::WSDL11` does NOT support nested schema files. Thus, they all have to be imported manually. This is sort of made a little simpler by the use of `glob`. However, the function is also unable to distinguish between `import` and `include`!

For all `xsd` files that are included (not imported), the `compileCalls()` fails because the compiler is unable to find the type-definitions in files from `include`d schemas:

> error: cannot find type {parent-namespace}SomeCustomType ...

Obviously, because the definitions were not correctly included into the parent's namespace. I verified this by manually editing some of the included schemas, explicitly adding `targetNamespace="parent-namespace"` within the `<xs:schema ..>` attribute of the included schemas.. and it worked!

So, do I really have to manually edit ALL of the inclusions, or does it exist a better approach than the `importDefinitions(glob "mySchema/*xsd")` function that will deal with `import` and `include` appropriately?

Comment: I wish I was surprised to hear this. Unfortunately, there are very few accurate implementations of the entire XML Schema standard. Some of the most popular XML processing tools fail to implement well-known rules. My first instinct would be to get hold of the source code and see whether I could fix the defect.

Comment: @kimbert, thanks for the input! I almost started editing all the schemas, but then I realized the implication of what happens whenever the servers changes the API and I'll need to download it all again, and reedit them all ... again. Also, I'll be working a lot with this schemas and other XML applications this year.. so, I'm now strongly considering your suggestion. Just download the `XML::Compile::WSDL11` source code and extend it to my own needs. Thanks!